# How to write placeholder vars in Netlify redirects file

Tags: redirect, gatsby, netlify

I am using a `_redirects` file in my gatsby build to force some redirects on some pages.

I’ve got a number of blog articles from my old site that have the following path characteristics:

```
example.com/my-blog-post-1
example.com/my-blog-post-2
```

I would like to use a variable, splat or wildcard sort of operator to turn the above URLs into this:

```
example.com/blog/my-blog-post-1
```

I've gone through the [docs on Netlify](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/) and they do mention using `:splat` and `placeholders`. Except for maybe `:splat`, the tools available there don't seem to fit my situation.

Anyone know a way to do this? Here's what I've got a.k.a *nothing*:

```
# posts
/my-blog-article/       /blog/{* or :splat ??} 301
```

In some `.htaccess` type files you can use variables like `$1` in the first value definition and then reference it in the second value definition but this isn't clearly mentioned in the Netlify docs.

N.B: also posted a similar question on the [netlify community forum](https://community.netlify.com/t/using-placeholder-or-wildcard-to-add-directory-to-redirects-path/17620)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is

```
/my-blog-article/      /blog/:splat
```

But just moving the files in gatsby to be in a `blog` directory is probably the easier and less error-prone option!

Comment: Ok, yes, this would work for a small number of posts but originally the solution needed to be variable and dynamic.

I think I was having an issue with `gatsby-plugin-sitemap` which was messing up all my relative URLs.

Your suggestion is correct that it's easier put all the posts in a 'blog' category, which I do. 

My solution was just to query with `graphql` the `path` of the post, and the correct path was there.